# When to use LM317 vs LM2941CT?

Tags: ldo, lm317, linear-regulator

A seller sent me by mistake a bunch of LM2941CT. I checked the specifications and I see they are interesting, especially given I'm running out of LM317.

I would like directions for choosing one over the other for small hobby projects, especially for those where I need adjustable and clean output (low power lab power supply).

What I already noticed:

- in LM317 it is suggested to change the resistor ADJ-GND to change the output voltage, in LM2941 it's suggested to change the resistor Vout-ADJ. It makes the use of linear pots straightforward.
- in LM2941 the minimum output is 5V, in LM317 it's 1.25V. Most of the time is ok, and when I want to go lower I guess it's possible to connect GND to a negative -5V rail (the same as getting 0-1.25V with the LM317).
- LM2941 requires a specific capacitor value and ESR
- LM2941 has way better ripple rejection than LM317 especially in 10-1000 kHz.

Anything else?

Comment: Compare the dropout voltage graphs

Comment: Lower maximum input voltage.  26V vs 40.  I also use the lm317HV which goes to 60V Vin.

Comment: LM317 dumps its operating current out the output so there is a minimum current of  10mA (typically 3.5mA- many published circuits depend on **luck** in this department) for regulation (can be provided by the feedback resistors).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the user never asked a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You've highlighted most of the details, but forgot the one big difference: the LM2941C is a LDO (Low DropOut) regulator. It uses a PNP as its main transistor, instead of a traditional NPN. So the droput voltage (voltage difference required between input and output) is 0.5V max, which is way better than the 2-2.5V of LM317.

And, by the way, this is why the ESR of the output capacitor then becomes important.

Now, a few other differences:

- LM2941C input/output voltages capabilities are lower than for LM317 (you certainly noticed, but you didn't mention it). Moreover, the "floating" topology of the LM317 actually allows you to regulate voltage supplies as high as you want, provided that you don't exceed the maximum voltage difference between input and output (this is detailed in the datasheet). The topology of the LM2941 doesn't allow this.
- current capabilities are lower as well (1A vs 1.5A)
- quiescent current (current wasted through ADJ or GND pin) is way higher for LM2941C (10-30mA vs 50µA), so it won't be appropriate for low-power designs running on batteries.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I was interested in non-obvious differences. The quiescent current is one, for example, that would kill the TLV431 (10 mA typical), meaning that getting an accurate and stable negative rail is non compact/trivial (op-amp as buffer, for example).